# 3 digits are truncated from an 18 digit long column when I save my pandas dataframe as a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, scientific-notation

I've created a dataframe from a dictionary populated by a JSON file. The **"id"** column in my dataframe contains 18 digits integer. When I print ids using python the value is equal to the original value in the JSON file, but when I try to save my dataframe as a csv file the id column is saved in scientific notation and also three digits on the right side of ids are converted to zero.
How can I prevent the id value conversion to scientific notation in the csv file?

For example, I get `1.01045E+17` for **id** when I view the csv, and when I see the value I get `101044874404577000`, while the true value is `101044874404577281`

This is my code:

```py
with open(data_path, encoding="utf8") as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv(output_path)
```

I have tried to change the format of the column by `astype` to `str`, `object`, and `float64` but that didn't help.
I've set `float_format` argument of `to_csv` function to save floating numbers with specified number of decimals, too. This didn't work either.

Comment: Sounds like a float conversion. Either comes from `json` or `pandas`. You should check your `data` dict to see if the value is correct. If it is, then you need to pass datatype to `from_dict`.

Comment: Did you try to convert the json column to int? I am not sure that will do the trick, but it seems that you are working with integers

Comment: How do you *view* a csv file? In a text editor like vi or notepad or in a spreadsheet like Excel which is known to badly process csv files?

Comment: No, as I said I have printed id column's value and it is correct. @QuangHoang

Comment: do not use `float64`, use `int` or `np.int64` instead.

Comment: @Jorge Yes I have tried that, it is integer, but it gets converted when I save my dataframe as a csv file.

Comment: You should make a reproducible example here: extract a few (problematic) `id`s to a new json file, try to run your code. Then post the sample, the code, and the output here.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I used Excel to view my file, but now I tried VS Code and it seems OK.
Thank you.

Comment: Sample input data is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in convertion to csv, but when you load it into a spreadsheet. Excel is known to have a poor support for csv files, and unfortunately LibreOffice calc does its best to emulate Excel...

It sees a number and wrongly convert it as a double value.

Demo:

In python:

```
>>> x = 101044874404577281
>>> data = [{"id": x, "str": "foo"}]
>>> fd = io.StringIO()
>>> json.dump(data, fd)
>>> fd.seek(0,0)
0
>>> df = pd.read_json(fd)
>>> print(df)
                   id  str
0  101044874404577281  foo
```

Ok everything is fine here. Let's go on:

```
>>> df.to_csv('foo.csv', index=False)
```

When opened in a dumb text editor, foo.csv if still fine:

```
id,str
101044874404577281,foo
```

Let's load that into a spreadsheet:

[image]

Shame on calc, it put that into scientific notation! Let's use normal display:

[image]

Sigh... it has destroyed the last digits...

TL/DR: It is not a problem in Python nor in pandas nor even with the csv file but only with Excel.